# Processing url parameters in email viewer app

Tags: javascript, android, url-parameters

Small backstory, I am trying to send contacts of mine a email message that contains a link to my website.  I want to track if they are clicking the link I sent them.  The only easy way I know how to do this is to include a url parameter in the link that identifies the contact.  Then when they land on my site test to see if the url contains the parameter.

I have been trying a few different scripts used to read url parameters.  The following code works great on desktops and mobile devices using a browser. However, I'm still running into an issue reading a parameter on a phone when using a email viewer app such a gmail.

The problem is when I use the built in gmail app on a phone and click a link that contains a parameter like this one:

> www.example.com/sub-folder/page.html?r=testValue

The app will open the link location in the gmail viewer instead of opening it in a browser like chrome (or another major browser).  When it does this for some reason the code below does not collect the parameter.  Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

The gmail app for android even shows an option to view the message in chrome.  When I do that my script reads the parameter just fine.  Only stops working in the apps built in viewer which unfortunately I'm sure more people just use the app viewer instead of trying to view it in chrome.

```
var myParam = GetURLparam('r');
function GetURLparam(p){
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++){
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == p){
            return decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried this script, but it only works on desktops for some odd reason:

```
var myParam = GetURLparamNOTWORKING('r');
function GetURLparamNOTWORKING(p){
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```